# Фиксированый блок(прокручивается со страницей)

Tags: javascript

Помогите пожалуйста, нужно написать js что бы блок прокручивался вместе со страницей.
[Пример.](http://btemplate.ru/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так:

```
<body>
  <div style = "width:100%; height: 100%; overflow: auto;">
    <!-- Тут содержимое страницы -->
  </div>
  <div style = "position: absolute; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px;">
    <!-- Прижатый блок -->
  </div>
</body>
```

Так-же можно воспользоваться предложением [[@LeD4eG](/users/1926/led4eg)](/users/1926/led4eg):

```
<body>
  <!-- Тут содержимое страницы -->
  <div style = "position: fixed; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px;">
    <!-- Прижатый блок -->
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @doove, timka_s дал Вам отличный совет! но, для Вашего сведения, есть ещё `position: fixed`.